# rxjs: - receive values emitted before subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

my `emit.next(1)` is lost, I want my subscriber to get that value. My subscriber can't subscribe until after the emit has already happened.

This answer suggests publish and connect [RxJs: how to get values emitted before we subscribe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281879/rxjs-how-to-get-values-emitted-before-we-subscribe) however I wasn't sure how to get it working:

```
console.log('make emit')
let emit = new Subject<number>();
console.log('make obs')
let obs = emit.asObservable()
console.log('emit 1')
emit.next(1)
console.log('subscribe')
obs.subscribe((v)=>console.log(v,'!'))
console.log('emit 2')
emit.next(2)
console.log('set timeout 1000 to emit')
setTimeout(()=>emit.next(3),1000)
console.log('done')
```

output:

```
make emit
main.bundle.js:1561 make obs
main.bundle.js:1563 emit 1
main.bundle.js:1565 subscribe
main.bundle.js:1567 emit 2
main.bundle.js:1566 2 "!"
main.bundle.js:1569 set timeout 1000 to emit
main.bundle.js:1571 done
main.bundle.js:1566 3 "!"
```

it should log `1 "!"`

Comment: I guess you can use `ReplaySubject`...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject` instead of `Subject` or plain `Observable`, then new subscribers will get the last emitted event as first value.

Comment: excellent this help me with a problem on my code 